# Having problems with big oh, Omega, theta

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show the following:

$\ $ (a) $\, \sum_{i=1}^n(3i+2n)\text{ is }O(n^2)$

$\ $ (b) $\, \sum_{k=1}^n(k/3)\text{ is }\Omega(n^2)$

$\ $ (c) $\, \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n 7n\text{ is }\Theta(n^3)$.

Thank you.

Comment: what exactly is your problem??

Comment: I've copied the formulas from the picture. Please check them. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sum can be separated, giving you $2n(n)+\sum_1^n 3i$, which gives you $2n^2+\frac32(n+1)n$. Clearly this is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$. The rest are similarly straightforward.

**Use the definitions.**